# Strange gap between the last two fieldsets

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

I am getting when i use a fieldset underneath the other fieldset a strange gap between, but that's not in my code...

Here's the css:

```
fieldset { overflow:hidden }
.some-class { float:left; clear:none; }
.some-class1 { float:left; clear:none; }
.some-class2 { float:left; clear:none; }
.someclass { float:left; clear:none; }
.someclass1 { float:left; clear:none; }
```

Here the html:

```
<fieldset>
  <div class="some-class">
             <input type="button" value="AAN" style="float:left" onclick="POI(this)" />

    <input type="button" value="UIT" style="float:left" onclick="POI(this)" />
   <span>Spoortoegang </span>

 </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <div class="someclass">
                 <input type="button" value="AAN" style="float:left" onclick="Storingen(this)" />

         <input type="button" value="UIT" style="float:left" onclick="Storingen(this)" />
  <span>Storingen</span>
 </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <div class="Tekeningen-class">
             <input type="button" value="AAN" style="float:left" onclick="Tekeningen(this)" />

    <input type="button" value="UIT" style="float:left" onclick="Tekeningen(this)" />
   <span>Tekeningen</span>

 </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <div class="someclass1">
                   <input type="button" value="AAN" style="float:left" onclick="Ultrasoon(this)" />
<input type="button" value="UIT" style="float:left;" onclick="Ultrasoon(this)" />
  <span>Ultrasoon Rapporten</span>
 </div>
 </fieldset>

   <fieldset>
  <div class="some-class2">
                   <input type="button" value="AAN" style="float:left" onclick="Medewerkers(this)" />
<input type="button" value="UIT" style="float:left;" onclick="Medewerkers(this)" />
  <span>Medewerkers</span>
 </div>
</fieldset>​
 <fieldset style="margin:0px; padding 0px;">

 <ul class="dropdown">
 <div id="some-class1"">
    <li><a id="drivers" onclick="dropdown(this); return false;" class="dir" style="font size=18"">IRISSYS Data &#9660;</a>
        <ul id="driversmenu" class="sub" >
<fieldset style="background-color:#c5ccd3">            
            <li><a>  <div class="someclass">
                   <input type="button" value="AAN" style="float:left" onclick="irisvoertuig(this)" />
<input type="button" value="UIT" style="float:left;" onclick="irisvoertuig(this)" />
  <span>Voertuig Effect</span></a></li>
</fieldset>

<fieldset style="background-color:#c5ccd3">            
            <li><a>  <div class="someclass">
                   <input type="button" value="AAN" style="float:left" onclick="iriscombinatie(this)" />
<input type="button" value="UIT" style="float:left;" onclick="iriscombinatie(this)" />
  <span>Combinatie Parameter</span></a></li>
</fieldset>

<fieldset style="background-color:#c5ccd3">            
            <li><a>  <div class="someclass">
                   <input type="button" value="AAN" style="float:left" onclick="irishoogte(this)" />
<input type="button" value="UIT" style="float:left;" onclick="irishoogte(this)" />
  <span>Hoogte</span></a></li>
</fieldset>

<fieldset style="background-color:#c5ccd3">            
            <li><a>  <div class="someclass">
                   <input type="button" value="AAN" style="float:left" onclick="irisschift(this)" />
<input type="button" value="UIT" style="float:left;" onclick="irisschift(this)" />
  <span>Schift</span></a></li>
</fieldset>

<fieldset style="background-color:#c5ccd3">            
            <li><a>  <div class="someclass">
                   <input type="button" value="AAN" style="float:left" onclick="irisverkanting(this)" />
<input type="button" value="UIT" style="float:left;" onclick="irisverkanting(this)" />
  <span>Verkanting verschil</span></a></li>
</fieldset>

<fieldset style="background-color:#c5ccd3">            
            <li><a>  <div class="someclass">
                   <input type="button" value="AAN" style="float:left" onclick="irisspoorwijdte(this)" />
<input type="button" value="UIT" style="float:left;" onclick="irisspoorwijdte(this)" />
  <span>Spoorwijdte Verloop</span></a></li>
</fieldset>

<fieldset style="background-color:#c5ccd3">            
            <li><a>  <div class="someclass">
                   <input type="button" value="AAN" style="float:left" onclick="irisspoorstaaf(this)" />
<input type="button" value="UIT" style="float:left;" onclick="irisspoortaaf(this)" />
  <span>Spoorstaaf Slijtage</span></a></li>
</fieldset>
<fieldset style="background-color:#c5ccd3">            
            <li><a>  <div class="someclass">
                   <input type="button" value="AAN" style="float:left" onclick="irissporen(this)" />
<input type="button" value="UIT" style="float:left;" onclick="irissporen(this)" />
  <span>IRISSYS Sporen</span></a></li>
</fieldset>

       </ul>
    </li>
        <div>

    </ul>
  </fieldset>
```

And in chrome's element inspector i get this:

[image: element inspector]

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?
Your help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you span might have a bottom border, what does the styles inspector say? Try removing the div, then the span, then both, do you still get the strange line? But...why are you using fieldset, just for graphical purposes? In which case, I'd suggest sticking to a div.

Comment: i spotted some floats, try `clear:both;`

Comment: I would say it's the nesting of fieldsets, ul, div's and li's thats causing your glitch. Dont put anything between ul and li, then you will be fine.

Comment: @Babboe Can you make a jsfiddle of it? it will be much helpful.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KPTXR/

Comment: Yes Babboe. In your jsFiddle see the red dot after the Medewerkers fieldset. Also in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ANSWER:**

There is an invisible character put in between the fieldsets, seen by some rendered as a red dot.

```
&#8203;
```

Remove that and your problem will go away.

http://jsfiddle.net/hsRSD/1/ or removed in your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KPTXR/1/

I removed the other part to make it easy to find.

```
 <fieldset>
    <span>Medewerkers</span>
 </fieldset>​  <-- It is here, but only seen in jsFiddle
 <fieldset style="margin:0px; padding 0px;">


  </fieldset>
```

**Advices:**

Then in your code you have some problems with double quotes:

```
 style="font size=18""   <-- remove the duplicate
```

(actually CSS is `font-size: 18px` )

Then be careful not to do nested UL's with other elements. I can tell many problems that comes from having other elements than LI directly under an UL.

```
 <ul id="driversmenu" class="sub" >
     <fieldset style="background-color:#c5ccd3">      <-- THIS will likely cause problems!    
        <li><a>  <div class="someclass">
            <input type="button" value="AAN" style="float:left" onclick="irisvoertuig(this)" />
            <input type="button" value="UIT" style="float:left;" onclick="irisvoertuig(this)" />
            <span>Voertuig Effect</span></a>
        </li>
     </fieldset>
```

If you have to have the fieldset there put it after the LI:

```
  <ul id="driversmenu" class="sub" >
     <li>
        <fieldset style="background-color:#c5ccd3">          
        <a> <-- what does this do?
          <div class="someclass">
            <input type="button" value="AAN" style="float:left" onclick="irisvoertuig(this)" />
            <input type="button" value="UIT" style="float:left;" onclick="irisvoertuig(this)" />
            <span>Voertuig Effect</span></a>
        </fieldset>
     </li>
```

​    ​

Comment: I don't quite get what i need to do? i shouldnt just delete the </fieldset>

Comment: Do you mean for the gap? Just delete the red dot. (probably invisible in your editor, just delete the spaces between...)

Comment: Yeah but how do i delete in in my program(Coda) when i can't see the red dot.